# How to exclude unpublished nodes from db_query results?

Tags: mysql, sql, drupal, drupal-7

How to **exclude unpublished nodes** via db_query?

I figured they are defined as

```
SELECT * FROM `node` WHERE status = '1'
```

but how to include that in the below drupal db_query?

```
function faq_search_find() {

  $term = strip_tags(drupal_substr($_POST['keyword'], 0, 100));

  $result = db_query("SELECT question, nid
  FROM {faq_questions}
  WHERE question LIKE :term
  ORDER BY question asc", array(':term' => '%%' . $term . '%%'));
  $string = "";

  while ($row = $result->fetchObject()) {
    $string .= "<a href='/" . drupal_get_path_alias('node/' . $row->nid) . "'>" . $row->question . "</a>";
  }

  echo $string;
  exit;
}
```

Could the searh be combined based on nid within the node table or would a better approach be to filter them out with a Drupal command in the while loop?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have to `AND status = 1` somewhere in that query. Maybe the snippets on https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_query/7.x can help you.

Comment: You may be better off using an `EntityFieldQuery`. https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/howtos/how-to-use-entityfieldquery-for-drupal-7

Comment: Thanks @leymannx The status is in another table though called node where the main query is against faq_questions hence I thought it would require some nesting or additional condition?

Comment: Re entityfieldquery, do you mean to replace the entire query incl. the condition for published or only apply it to $result? 

FYI - This is for a keyword search for faq module across faq nodes.

Comment: Yes, to replace the entire query with EFQ.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look into it more, i don't have experience with building queries just understand the database query concept a bit :) just curious why you think it would be better with EFQ? Easier or perhaps advantage?

Comment: Mere readability first. That makes it much better to maintain in the future. And you are on entity level anyways so why not using the functions that are made for that.

Comment: Use EntityFieldQuery or join the node table to your query

Comment: @EricLavault thanks, I will look into EFQ as it might make it easier to change the query in future. in meantime could you tell me how to join the node table query please?

I'm not SQL savvy but understand it would probably have to take the 'nid' from the main query to cross check in the other table "node" where in that row the "status" = 1 and otherwise exclude it.

Comment: `SELECT f.question, f.nid 
FROM {faq_questions} f 
INNER JOIN {node} n ON f.nid = n.nid 
WHERE f.question LIKE :term 
ORDER BY f.question asc`

Comment: thanks @EricLavault , I think this is still missing the check in the INNER JOIN query for status = 1 because nodes not published are still being returned.
Do i need to use **AND**, something like `INNER JOIN {node} n ON f.nid = n.nid  AND f.status = 1` ?

Comment: @EricLavault I think i might have got it right now, which is working as desired, using **ON** to add the check for **n.nid**, is this correct?

`FROM {faq_questions} f INNER JOIN {node} n ON f.nid = n.nid AND n.status = 1`

Comment: Haha sorry I forgot the main thing !! :o Yes you can restrict how the `node` table is joined to the main table by adding the condition to the INNER JOIN clause like you did, you can also append the condition to the `WHERE` clause : `...  INNER JOIN {node} n ON f.nid = n.nid WHERE f.question LIKE :term AND n.status = 1 ORDER BY f.question asc`

Comment: thanks again Eric, learning lots and without you didn't think I would have gotten that far, awesome. Ultimately I have to include another table in the search and thus opened another question, no pressure but in case you can chime in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49676437/drupal-sql-conditional-clauses-for-multiple-tables

Answer (score 2):

You can join to the node table, or you can use an EFQ as comments above suggest. But here's the SQL

```
   $result = db_query("SELECT question, nid
     FROM {faq_questions} F1
     INNER JOIN {node} N1
     ON F1.nid = N1.nid AND N1.status = 1
     WHERE question LIKE :term
     ORDER BY question asc", array(':term' => '%%' . $term . '%%'));
```

In case you wanted an actual explanation as to why you should use an EFQ... while there are often cases where SQL is the right tool for the job, this really is not one of those. By writing raw SQL, you are tying your logic directly to database schema over which you have no control. If a future module update were to alter the schema, you would have broken code that would need updating.

While the node table is not likely to change in any significant way, the faq_questions table certainly could.