# drupal sql conditional clauses for multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, drupal, drupal-7

I have the below query for FAQ search module modified that works in Drupal 7,
which searches in two tables: 1) title 2) body but don't manage to include one more.

```
$term = strip_tags(drupal_substr($_POST['keyword'], 0, 100));

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT fq.title, fq.nid
 FROM {node} AS fq, {field_data_body} AS f
 WHERE fq.title LIKE :term
 OR fq.type LIKE :term
 OR f.body_value LIKE :term
 AND f.entity_id = fq.nid";

$result = db_query($query, array(':term' => '%%' . $term . '%%',':term' => '%%' . $term . '%%',':term' => '%%' . $term . '%%'));
```

I'd like to add one more to include detailed questions field in the search, but I think the linking for nid is the issue? I tried putting both into a clause but seems to be wrong. Help Please :)

> AND (fd.entity_id = fq.nid OR fb.entity_id = fq.nid)";

```
$term = strip_tags(drupal_substr($_POST['keyword'], 0, 100));
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT fq.title, fq.nid
    FROM {node} AS fq, {field_data_field_detailed_question} AS fd, {field_data_body} AS fb
    WHERE fq.title LIKE :term
    OR fd.field_detailed_question_value LIKE :term
    OR fb.body_value LIKE :term
    AND (fd.entity_id = fq.nid OR fb.entity_id = fq.nid)";
$result = db_query($query, array(':term' => '%%' . $term . '%%',':term' => '%%' . $term . '%%',':term' => '%%' . $term . '%%'));

$string = "";
while ($row = $result->fetchObject()) {
    $string .= "<a href='/" . drupal_get_path_alias('node/' . $row->nid) . "'>" . $row->title . "</a>"; 
}
echo $string;
```

**UPDATE:** Thanks to Syscall who helped me make his approach work (see chat).

I also managed to remove empty whitespace (by adding a new variable and using array_filter > I guess the issue was splitting whitespace and trim at the same time that array_map still created empty strings.) and adding a condition to exclude nodes not published via db_and() referencing n.status = 1.

```
$terms = explode(' ', $term); // split using ' '
$terms = array_map('trim', $terms); // remove unwanted spaces
$termsfiltered = array_filter($terms);
$or = db_or();
foreach ($termsfiltered as $term) {
    $or->condition('fd.field_detailed_question_value', '%'.db_like($term).'%', 'LIKE');
    $or->condition('fb.body_value','%'.db_like($term).'%' , 'LIKE');
    $or->condition('n.title','%'.db_like($term).'%' , 'LIKE');
}
$and = db_and()->condition('n.status','1' , 'LIKE');

$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->fields('n');
$query->leftJoin('field_data_body' , 'fb', 'fb.entity_id=n.nid');
$query->leftJoin('field_data_field_detailed_question' ,'fd', 'fd.entity_id=n.nid');
$query->condition($or);
$query->condition($and);
$stmt = $query->execute(); // execute the query (returns the "statement" to fetch).
```

p.s. inserting **var_dump($variabletodump);** was really helpful while changing the code and viewing the effects of the arrays to solve issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot chain `leftJoin` (or any `join`) in Drupal queries, because [`leftJoin()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3AleftJoin/7.x) returns the alias, not the query. Then you should use [`execute()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21query.inc/function/Query%3A%3Aexecute/7.x) to "run" the query.

```php
$or = db_or()
  ->condition('fd.field_detailed_question_value', '%'.db_like($term ).'%', 'LIKE')
  ->condition('fb.body_value','%'.db_like($term ).'%' , 'LIKE');

$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->fields('n');
$query->leftJoin('field_data_body' , 'fb', 'fb.entity_id=n.nid');
$query->leftJoin('field_data_field_detailed_question' ,'fd', 'fd.entity_id=n.nid');
$query->condition($or);
$stmt = $query->execute(); // execute the query (returns the "statement" to fetch).

while ($row = $stmt->fetchObject()) {
    //..
}
```

You have to add fields :

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n')->fields('n');
```

or

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
         ->addField('n','title')
         ->addField('n','nid');
```

Comment: thanks @Syscall! I've seen similar examples and was already wondering. I tried you'rs which didn't give me errors but not returning any results yet :( I double checked the table and column names and they sound good.
Should this work with
 `$string = "";
 while ($row = $result->fetchObject()) {
    $string .= "<a href='/" . drupal_get_path_alias('node/' . $row->nid) . "'>" . $row->title . "</a>"; }
echo $string;` ?

Comment: not sure,  the while loop is supposed to print the results but nothing is displayed. (not sure how else I can check the array while performing the search)

Comment: @Markus Please try `$results = $stmt->fetchAll(); var_dump($results);`. A note, you could use `<a href="'.url('node/'.$row->nid).'">...</a>` (without initial slash).

Comment: @Markus Oh! Did you have a `$query->addField('n','title');` ? You need to have something between the `SELECT` and `FROM`. See [`addField()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery::addField/7.x) or `$query->fields('n');`. (See [`fields()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3Afields/7.x) - I've updated the answer (`See db_select()->fields()`).

Comment: no i didn't see that in your answer (please add) I placed it underneath the first $query line. vardump is needed or for testing?
Need to doublecheck if I got that ahref right

Comment: var_dump() is for debugging. Please refresh your page, the answer was updated - see the final part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168333/discussion-between-markus-and-syscall).

Comment: sorry didn't realise I can only accept one answer. thanks for pointing out and just changed it back.
Re chaining, is the solution we discussed still incorrect? (current code in my updated)
`$query->leftJoin('field_data_body' , 'fb', 'fb.entity_id=n.nid'); 
$query->leftJoin('field_data_field_detailed_question' ,'fd', 'fd.entity_id=n.nid'); `
I'm available in the chat if you have some more time, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$or = db_or()
  ->condition('fd.field_detailed_question_value', '%'.db_like($term ).'%', 'LIKE')
  ->condition('fb.body_value','%'.db_like($term ).'%' , 'LIKE');

$results = db_select('node', 'n')
  ->fields('n', array('nid', 'title'))
  ->leftJoin('field_data_body' , 'fb', 'fb.entity_id=n.nid')
  ->leftJoin('field_data_field_detailed_question' ,'fd', 'fd.entity_id=n.nid')
  ->condition($or)
  ->execute()
  ->fetchAll();

var_dump($results);
```

[db_select documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7.x)

[db_or documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_or/7.x)

Comment: wow thanks @Fky! I'd like to learn more about drupal query, this helps a lot. I tried it but got `"FATAL ERROR: CALL TO A MEMBER FUNCTION LEFTJOIN() "` for 2nd leftJoin.
(I understand this is EFQ instead of the SQL query thus this replaces my entire $query).

Comment: I miss fields instruction so i edited my post you can try again @Markus

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try later on, looks very close to the other one based on your original post as first answer :)
When $term has multiple keywords ie. "Test orange apple" , what would be best way to let the query search for any of the words (like phpmyadmin has this search function)?

I'm concerned whether this might be a very complex query but just realised without it when people have  multiple keywords they won't get any results (and probably think it's not working / worse UX). Probably should open a new question ?

Comment: FYI - Just seen Syscall added some comments in the chat to use $terms with explode, array_map and loop through with foreach. Will try that. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168333/discussion-between-markus-and-syscall